# How to generate android resource(string, dimen etc.) using by annotation processing?

Tags: java, android, annotation-processing

I would like generate string resource from annotation.

```
@StringKey("style1")
void applyStyle1(){...}
```

After compile project:

```
<resources>
 <!-- Automatically generated file. DO NOT MODIFY -->
 <!-- Values from product flavor: prod -->
 <string name="style1" translatable="false">style1</string>
</resources>
```

Value does not matter

Comment: A very specific use case. I'd suggest you to read how to write your own custom annotation processor:
http://hannesdorfmann.com/annotation-processing/annotationprocessing101

Comment: It's not annotation processing but are you looking for [`resValue` in build script](https://www.tanelikorri.com/tutorial/android/set-variables-in-build-gradle/)?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to achieve something like this ?

```
@ViewById
EditText myEditText;

@ViewById(R.id.myTextView)
TextView textView;

@StringRes(R.string.hello)
String helloFormat; //helloFormat will have the value of R.string.hello at runtime 

@ColorRes
int androidColor;

@BooleanRes
boolean someBoolean;

@SystemService
NotificationManager notificationManager;

@SystemService
WindowManager windowManager;
```

If so , then have a look at https://github.com/androidannotations